# C# method gives me an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created one method in c# that has two parameters. I have just changed its parameter name but now it is giving me old parameters value. And the error is coming while runtime.

This is new method which i have changed its parameter

```
public void UpdatePagedDataSet(string configKey, string configValue)
{
---SOME CODE---
}
```

This is old method works fine

```
public void UpdatePagedDataSet(string CONFIGKEY, string CONFIGVALUE)
{
---SOME CODE---
}
```

Error:

```
could not find a non-generic method 'UpdatePagedDataSet' that has parameters: CONFIG_VALUE, configKey, configValue
```

What is the mistake i have done...??

Comment: What specific error does it throw? And I'm assuming you've updated all references of the lowercase versions of the parameters...

Comment: Where are you calling this method from? which values are you getting as arguments, and which values do you expect to get?

Comment: which Error ? what do you mean you get old values?

Comment: I have updated the question and put error in it..

Comment: did you replaced all the instances of the variables with their new names ?

Comment: Show the code where you are **calling** this method, since that is obviously the problem area.

Comment: -1 I think that you play with us, also not giving the real function call. As you giving this there is not error at all, now if you have other code that make the error, is not here.

Comment: @GrantWinney: It is old name of parameter

Comment: @Aristos: I am putting in Objectdatasource...thats it.

Comment: The error have 3 parameters, the functions 2. (and with different names) Its probably a rebuild issue, but the code you show here is not the mirror of the error.

Answer (score 5):

This commonly happens if you have not re-built.

Click

```
Build->Rebuild solution
```

in visual studio.

-- Edit to reflect the change in question/information --

It looks like you are missing an overloaded function

```
public void UpdatePagedDataSet(string CONFIG_VALUE, string configKey, string configValue)
{
---SOME CODE---
}
```

When your calling the function have you accidently called it with 3 parameters instead of 2?

Answer (score 3):

The problem doesn't seem to be related to the method not being recongnized but with wrong amount of parameters.

According the error description, 3 parameters are sent to `UpdatePagedDataSet` method  (`CONFIG_VALUE, configKey, configValue`) while 2 are expected (`configKey, configValue`).

Please paste how you're calling that method.

Comment: I am calling this method in Objectdatasource as UpdateMethod.

Comment: @user968441: please add to the question your ObjectDataSource  definition.